# YQL API Request Private Data Authentication Error

Tags: php, oauth, yql

I am using YQL to pull some data for my yahoo fantasy football league. I have created the app and it gave me a consumer/secret key but how do I pass this information to the yahoo api to log me in? I know I have to use OAuth but I am not sure how to use the key in tandem with CURL and YQL

Here is my PHP Code:

```
<pre>
<?php
  $BASE_URL = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql";

    // Form YQL query and build URI to YQL Web service
    $yql_query = "select * from fantasysports.leagues.standings where league_key='331.l.777400'";
    $yql_query_url = $BASE_URL . "?q=" . urlencode($yql_query) . "&format=json";

    // Make call with cURL
    $session = curl_init($yql_query_url);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    $json = curl_exec($session);
    // Convert JSON to PHP object 
    $phpObj =  json_decode($json);
    var_dump($phpObj);
?>
</pre>
```

and the error I get is

> "Authentication Error.  The table fantasysports.leagues.standings
>   requires a higher security level than is provided, you provided ANY
>   but at least USER is expected"

Comment: I've got this msg before when using the console, but by logging out and logging-in it would go away. You are doing code access so perhaps you need to pass credentials?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this?